# how do i build an entire mailto anchor in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, anchor, stringbuilder

I have a literal tag which is passed a list of string. one of the string i wish to pass to it is an email.. i would like the email to be an hyperlink. this is what i have got so far,

```
tenancyManager.UserEmail = "a@b.c";
if (null != tenancyManager.UserEmail)
{
    var emailAnchor = "<a href="+"mailto:"+tenancyManager.UserEmail+">"+ "</a>";
    builder.Append(emailAnchor);
    builder.Append("<br />");
}
```

this doesnt seem to work, can anyone help with my syntax? i have also tried

```
var email = string.Format("<a href={0}{1} Text={2}> </a>", "mailto:", tenancyManager.UserEmail, tenancyManager.UserEmail);
```

Comment: Maybe put some text in the anchor tag?

Comment: By 'doesn't seem to work', what do you mean?  Are you getting an exception?  Is the variable in your `emailAnchor` being set or returning `null`?  More information is always better...

Comment: Also in your `String.Format` you have more format items than you do parameters..  That'll throw an error.

Comment: why do you use a literal and not an asp:hyperlink??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `string.Format()` code is wrong. Try:

```
var email = string.Format("<a href='mailto:{0}'>{0}</a>", tenancyManager.UserEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (HtmlTextWriter tag = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    tag.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, string.Format("mailto:{0}", tenancyManager.UserEmail));
    tag.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
    tag.Write(tenancyManager.UserEmail);
    tag.RenderEndTag();

}
literal.Text = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Though I'm not sure why you don't just use an `<asp:Hyperlink>`? Like so:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hypEmail" runat="server" />
hypEmail.NavigateUrl = string.Format("mailto:{0}", tenancyManager.UserEmail);
hypEmail.Text = string.Format("mailto:{0}", tenancyManager.UserEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatString is wrong: the a html tag does not have a text attribute.

```
string.Format("<a href=\"mailto:{0}\">{0}</a>", tenancyManager.UserEmail);
```

(it does not make sense to use `string.format` with 2 different placeholder for the same text)

Anyway i think it is more clean to use an `asp:HyperLink` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx instead of a literal.

```
hl.NavigateUrl = string.Format("mailto:{0}", tenancyManager.UserEmail);
hl.Text = tenancyManager.UserEmail;
```

Or if you want to have full html output control use the `GenericHtmlControl` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx
 or the `HtmlAnchor` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx

IMHO Use Literal control to inject html is a bad practice

Comment: I REALLY wonder why someone downvote my answer. if someone doesn't agree with an answer it should argue it instead of hiding under anonymity. TThis is the foundation of stackexchange network. IMHO